# enter in mysql without password should not work

Tags: mysql

On windows, I have two root users.
I deleted one and kept the local one (root@localhost).
I set its password by :

```
set password for 'root'@'localhost'= password('new_password');
```

I exit and I do :

```
mysql -u root
```

and I am in mysql.
I was waiting for the password request.

Answer (score 1):

You have to restart mysql or run `flush privilidges` before the new password will take effect.

Also try setting root password for 127.0.0.1 as well as localhost.

Comment: @Bertaud Did you flush privs then log out and in?  Also do a select * from mysql.user where user='root' ; and make sure the password is set for root

Comment: I was already out of mysql. So I restarted the service. The password is correctly set to root. 127.0.0.1 is unuseful ?

Comment: @Bertaud When logged in as root, run 'show processlist;'. You should see the connection you are logged in as.  Is it root@localhost

Comment: 2 lines: user_scheduler/localhost and root/localhost:25411

Comment: @Bertaud last thing i can think of wourld be your my.cnf file could have root password settings in it.